# Everyone is getting sick! What can I do?

Tags: the-oregon-trail-40th-anniversary

First my son got the mumps. Then my wife got dysentery. I don't want them to die, but when I was told they were sick, my only option was to "ignore it".

Is there anything else I can do to make sure they get better? I quite like my family members, and would be sad if they died.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use medicine.**

That's the easy answer, but the not-so-easy part is finding it. The supplies merchants I have seen don't have any. So far the only place I found it was from a stranger on the road. He offered me two medicine for a nominal fee (20 or 40 dollars I think).

I used the medicine to cure both Mumps and a broken leg, so I assume its a blanket cure for all injuries/illnesses.

Will edit if I find any other sources of medicine.

Comment: I figured I could use medicine (I remember someone wanting to trade for it, but I didn't have any), but I had no idea where to get it. I also saw a doctor once randomly on the trail, but no one was sick then, so it didn't help me any.

Comment: Did the doctor offer medicine to sell or just a "heal while you're here" type thing?

Comment: he just offered to heal someone (in this case, he picked my son, who wasn't sick at the time).